# ffmpeg concat multiple videos with fade

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I want to combine several videos with transitions between videos. Ideally, I want to get a command that can merge multiple videos. Or at least get a pattern of how to generate a command programmatically for many videos.

Currently I have next command:

```shell
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]xfade=duration=1:offset=26[outv]; \
[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=duration=1[outa]; \
[1:v][2:v]xfade=duration=1:offset=44[outv]; \
[1:a][2:a]acrossfade=duration=1[outa]" -map [outv] -map [outa] Output.mp4
```

And I get next error:

`Filter acrossfade:default has an unconnected output`

Full error:

```shell
Error: Command failed: ffmpeg -i /video1.mp4 -i /video2.mp4 -i /video3.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]xfade=duration=1:offset=26[outv]; [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=duration=1[outa];  [1:v][2:v]xfade=duration=1:offset=44[outv]; [1:a][2:a]acrossfade=duration=1[outa]"   -map [outv] -map [outa] Output.mp4
ffmpeg version 5.1-0ubuntu1~20.04.sav0 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='0ubuntu1~20.04.sav0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-lcms2 --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libdav1d --enable-libjxl --enable-librist --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-crystalhd --enable-libmfx --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/video1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:26.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6110 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 6032 kb/s, 60.04 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/video2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:17.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6174 kb/s
  Stream #1:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 6095 kb/s, 60.06 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #1:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/video3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:17.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6073 kb/s
  Stream #2:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 5995 kb/s, 60.06 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #2:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Filter acrossfade:default has an unconnected output
```

Comment: Could it be the duplicate label?: https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/mriyp5/filter_amix_has_an_unconnected_output/

Comment: Try something like `ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]xfade=duration=1:offset=1[outv];[outv][2:v]xfade=duration=1:offset=1[outv]" -map [outv] output.mp4`. The output of the first `xfade` is `[outv]`, and the input of the second `xfade` is `[outv][2:v]`.

Comment: @Rotem I tried. But for some reason, only 2 videos were combined, 3 are not.

Comment: Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63553906/merging-multiple-video-files-with-ffmpeg-and-xfade-filter). Example using 3 synthetic videos: **1.** `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10 -vcodec libx264 video1.mp4` **2.** `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=size=192x108:rate=1 -vcodec libx264 -t 10 video2.mp4` **3.** `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i life=s=192x108:mold=10:r=1:ratio=0.1:death_color=#C83232:life_color=#00ff00,scale=192:108:flags=16 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv444p -t 10 video3.mp4`

Comment: **4.** `ffmpeg -y -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]xfade=duration=2:offset=3[outv];[outv][2:v]xfade=duration=2:offset=10[outv]" -map [outv] output.mp4`

Answer (score 2):

I found [this website](https://romander.github.io/ffmpeg-script-generator/), it clearly shows how to generate the required script

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page change.